# AddHandler for PHP with different file extension

Tags: linux, php, .htaccess, apache2

I'm trying to configure a hosted Apache server, via `.htaccess`, to execute files with `.asp` extension with PHP. **But I don't know what the correct `handler-name` for `AddHandler` is.**

The reason is that we have a flash app that is GET requesting `.asp` files. We will re-write the `.asp` files in PHP but we can **not** change the flash app (we don't even have the source code).

I have tried to use the `AddHandler` and `AddType` directives.

```
AddHandler php-fcgid .php .asp
AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .asp
```

*Examples of directives I have tried to no avail*

Most give *No input file specified.* or set the mime-type to `application/x-httpd-php` for `.php` files (technically setting the `Content-Type` HTTP header).

Now, I fully understand `AddHandler` and `AddType` - the best resource I have found is https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4557229.htm#msg4557505.

The host has, what looks like a custom dash-board for administrating the server. I can change PHP version, from 5.4 to 7.0 and change some settings in `php.ini`.

I uploaded a `phpinfo();` and some of the values I think is relevant is posted below. The Apache version is unknown as it just report `Server: Apache`. But I'm sure it is at least Apache2, since *Apache 2.0 Handler* is listed under SAPI Modules.

**How can I figure out what the correct `handler-name` for `AddHandler` is?**

#### PHP Version 7.0.9

```
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /compile/php70/dest/lib
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/custom_php_config/slavespillet.dk/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20151012
```

#### cgi-fcgi

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cgi.check_shebang_line  1   1
cgi.discard_path    0   0
cgi.fix_pathinfo    1   1
cgi.force_redirect  1   1
cgi.nph 0   0
cgi.redirect_status_env no value    no value
cgi.rfc2616_headers 0   0
fastcgi.logging 1   1
```

#### Core

```
PHP Version     7.0.9
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] Apache
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround/alternative is to simply rewrite the `.asp` request to `.php` and store your files as ordinary `.php` files - assuming `.php` files are served correctly. Using mod_rewrite you could do something like the following in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.asp$ $1.php [L]
```

This would *internally rewrite* a request for `/path/to/something.asp` to `/path/to/something.php`.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines and implemented a re-write instead, since guessing the Action `action-type` name on a host seems feeble. I updated my RewriteRule with yours though as it is simpler. Thanks. Gonna leave the question unanswered for some hours, just in case someone comes up with the answer.

Comment: Using this method you could be selective about which files you rewrite... perhaps just those in a certain directory/URL-path (you could use another `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory just for that purpose) or even just the specific file(s). This is arguably preferable to implementing a handler to push all `.asp` files through PHP, when that might not be necessary.

Comment: Well, couldn't I also do that with the <Directory path>AddHandler php-fcgid .php .asp</Directory> directive?

Comment: Yes - kind of. You could use the appropriate `AddHandler`/`AddType` directive in the `.htaccess` file in that directory. The `<Directory>` directive is only permitted in your server config / VirtualHost.